# How to pass logged-in user Thread.CurrentPrincipal to WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, security, asp.net-identity

I am new to WCF and can't get my head around some real basic WCF principals.

What I have is a MVC website with an authenticated user, which I can access via Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

It is my understanding that I should be able to access this logged in user principal on the service once it is called via the Channel?

Can you kindly tell me if it is possible to have the currentprincipal passed to the service so I am able to use the Thread.CurrentPrincipal on the service and if so the bindings/config I would need.

Comment: what type of authentication is your mvc app using?

Comment: i believe "classic" forms authentication